# Can someone explain this integral $\int (4-t)\sqrt t dt $

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is the integral of

$$\int (4-t)\sqrt t\,\mathrm dt = -\frac2{15}t^{\frac32}(3t-20)$$

That’s what WolframAlpha says but I can’t figure out how it got there.

Comment: Please google how to write mathematics statements in stack exchange so that the statement is easier to read. Also, please go into a bit more detail about what you've tried so far in order to solve the problem, because that is usually the best way for us to see how we can help. Lastly, always make sure that you say what variable we are taking the integral with respect to, even though it might be obvious from the question.

Answer (score 2):

Note,

$$\int (4-t)\sqrt t\,\mathrm dt = 4\int  t^{\frac12}\,\mathrm dt - \int t^{\frac32}\,\mathrm dt =\frac83 t^{\frac32} -\frac25 t^{\frac52} = -\frac2{15}t^{\frac32}(3t-20)$$